# determining if a Class object is an instance of an abstract class

Tags: java, object, instance, abstract

I'm trying to determine if a generic class object is an instance of an abstract class.  So far I'm not having much luck.  Below is the code I'm trying to use. AbstractActivity is the name of a parent class I extend some of my activities from.

```
public void startActivity(Intent intent)
{
    ComponentName name = intent.getComponent();

    if(name != null)
    {
        Class<?> cls = null;
        try {
            cls = Class.forName(name.getClassName());

            if(cls.isInstance(AbstractActivity));
            {
                //do something
            }
            else
            {
                super.startActivity(intent);
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    super.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Nitpick - it can only be an instance of a non-abstract subclass of an abstract class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would try:

```
if(AbstractActivity.class.isAssignableFrom(cls)) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can base on simplename of class.

```
this.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(LauncherActivity.class.getSimpleName())
```